# Spark Streaming : Join Dstream batches into single output Folder

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, twitter-streaming-api

I am using Spark Streaming to fetch tweets from twitter by creating a StreamingContext as :
 `val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[3]", "TwitterFeed",Minutes(1))`

and creating twitter stream as :
`val tweetStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(new OAuthAuthorization(Util.config)),filters)`

then saving it as text file 
`tweets.repartition(1).saveAsTextFiles("/tmp/spark_testing/")`

and the problem is that the tweets are being saved as folders based on batch time but I need all the data of each batch in a same folder.

Is there any workaround for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this using Spark SQL's new DataFrame saving API which allow appending to an existing output. By default, saveAsTextFile, won't be able to save to a directory with existing data (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#save-modes ). https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations covers how to setup a Spark SQL context for use with Spark Streaming.

Assuming you copy the part from the guide with the SQLContextSingleton, The resulting code would look something like:

```
data.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
  // Convert your data to a DataFrame, depends on the structure of your data
  val df = ....
  df.save("org.apache.spark.sql.json", SaveMode.Append, Map("path" -> path.toString))
}
```

(Note the above example used JSON to save the result, but you can use different output formats too).

Comment: Can I save the  DF as text file ? As i haven seen default type is parquet. what should the source be?

Comment: @Holden, @HussainShaik I had the same question and used your solution but keep getting an error  - not found: value path
`[error]      df.save("com.databricks.spark.csv",SaveMode.Append,Map("path" ->path.toString))`. Any way to fix this?

Comment: requires that path is defined as the place you want to save it.

Comment: @Holden thanks..I figured it out. If I may ask another question... I am trying to collect tweets in this one file. The file now gets created all right but I don't see any tweets being saved in it. Heres my code snippet:

Comment: @serendipity: your code snippet didn't post. You would probably be better off creating another question rather than using the comments on this one.

Comment: @Holden I did that already yesterday...should have pasted the link of that question in here. Here goes: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693971/saving-twitter-streams-into-a-single-file-with-spark-streaming-scala). Thanks for your help