# Saving twitter streams into a single file with spark streaming, scala

Tags: scala, twitter, spark-streaming

So after help from this answer [Spark Streaming : Join Dstream batches into single output Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237877/spark-streaming-join-dstream-batches-into-single-output-folder) I was able to create a single file for my twitter streams. However,now I don't see any tweets being saved in this file. Please find below my code snippet for this. What am I doing wrong?

```
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
        val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)
        val tweets = stream.map(r => r.getText)

        tweets.foreachRDD{rdd =>    
        val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        val df = rdd.map(t => Record(t)).toDF()
        df.save("com.databricks.spark.csv",SaveMode.Append,Map("path"->"tweetstream.csv")
}
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination() 
    }
```